# How to change the position and properties of the axes in matlab geoshow

Tags: matlab

I want to create a map by using worldmap and some shapefiles, but the font size of the axes are too small for my purpose and also the x-axis should be outside of the plot. But until now I couldn't solve the problem.

I tried to change the font size by using `set(gca,'FontSize', 20)` and also with `axism` but both did't work.

```
S = shaperead('BRA_water_areas_dcw.shp');
index = find(strcmp({S.NAME}, 'RIO TAPAJOS')==1)
shapewrite(S(index), 'TapajosRiver')

figure
%h = worldmap('Brazil')
%h = worldmap([-10.6754 1.4350], [-67.3784 -35.2984])
h = worldmap([-22.7933 5.7], [-69.2028 -32.2213])
m = getm(h, 'MapProjection')
geoshow('landareas.shp', 'FaceColor', [0.15 0.7 0.15])
geoshow('BRA_water_areas_dcw.shp', 'FaceColor', 'blue')
geoshow('TapajosRiver.shp', 'FaceColor', 'red')
set(gca,'FontSize', 22,'FontWeight','bold')
```

The current graphic looks like the following:
[image]

Comment: Try setting the fontsize with `set(findall(gca, 'type', 'text'),'FontSize', yoursize)`

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Dennis please post your own answer to indicate that this problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem with the font size, the code rinkert suggested can be used:

`set(findall(gca, 'type', 'text'),'FontSize', yoursize)`